# Simple migrations in Realm for Xamarin

Tags: .net, xamarin, realm, realm-migration, realm-net

The documentation of Realm for Xamarin says:

> Realm will automatically perform migrations that can be done without processing, like adding and removing classes or adding and removing properties from a class. For more complex changes, a proper migration is required. We do not yet have an API for this, but it is planned and will be added soon.

However, even when I just add a new field to a model, the app crash due to a required migration.

My question is: How can I make use of automatically performed migrations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a known documentation issue: https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/669

What you can do it is explicitly increment the schema version each time your simple model changes:

```
var config = RealmConfiguration.DefaultConfiguration;
config.SchemaVersion = 1;  // increment this when your model changes
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @SushiHangover is spot on. The documentation is still pending as we have had problems with our 0.77 release.

It is more of a *protection* than a *limitation* as it allows you to catch errors and prompt the user. *Completely automatic* migrations would make it a bit too easy to deploy code which made their files no longer backward compatible.